# Could not create listener socket on port 8000

Tags: icecast

This is the error when trying to run icecast2 from the serving using the terminal (command line): `sudo icecast2 -b -c /etc/icecast2/icecast.xml`

Error message:

> EROR connection/connection_setup_sockets Could not create listener socket on 
>       port 8000
>       EROR connection/connection_setup_sockets No listening sockets established
>       Server startup failed. Exiting

I can load the icecast server from browser BUT no mount points. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like Icecast is already running.
Why are you trying to start it manually? You should use systemd or the init script that comes with the Icecast package of your distribution.